# Create AWS::ECR::Repository resource by Cloudformation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, docker, repository, aws-cloudformation

I want to create repositories in my ECS cluster, using this syntax :

```
"PrincipalRepository": {
  "Type" : "AWS::ECR::Repository",
  "Properties" : {
    "RepositoryName" : String,
    "RepositoryPolicyText" : JSON object
  }
}
```

My question is: how to configure also the docker image in the template, and the repository URI : `account.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/repoName` ? Because I think this template will just give an empty repository. Am I right?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will indeed create an empty repository. You will need to do a `docker push ...` after building the image on a docker host.

See the *View Push Commands* button in the ECS Repository console.